# how to restrict unverified user to login in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to restrict User to login in DNN until his email id is not verified , if it is unverified user , the user not able to login in DNN, I made a Custom Registration page in DNN 
I used this code to restrict user:-

```
userInfo.Membership.Approved = false;
```

But It Wont Work, please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Support for unverified users was [added in DNN 6.2](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Default-roles.aspx).  All users who have registered but not verified will be in the Unverified Users role.  You should be able to restrict their access to the site using that role.  You will also need to change the registration type to Verified in Site Settings.

Or you can change the registration type to Private, requiring administrators to verify users before they can login.  This is [the new default registration type as of DNN 7.0](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/cid/144451/Site-registration-changes-in-DotNetNuke-7-0.aspx).

Comment: How to restrict the User to Login in case of Unverified User role in DNN 6 ? In DNN 7 also if I change the registration type to private, I have not received mail for verfication of account , the mail goes to administrator for approval, how i verified my email id through the verification mail and then I am able to Login in DNN?

Comment: You'll want to use _verified_ registration, rather than _private_.  You'll then need to adjust the permissions on each page, other than the Login page, to only allow the Registered Users role.  You can use the Page Management module under the Admin menu to do this a little more quickly than manually visiting each page.